# Join array in nim

Tags: nim-lang

I'm not entirely sure why, but I can't figure out how to join an array in Nim, here's the code:

```
import std/strformat

proc check(to: int, multi: int, toreturn: string): string = 
  if to mod multi == 0:
    return toreturn
  else:
    return ""

proc ifempty(str :string, num: int): string =
  if len(str) == 0:
    return fmt"{num}"
  else:
    return str

var i: int = 1
while i <= 100:
  var checks = @[check(i, 3, "Fizz"), check(i, 5, "Buzz")]
  let toecho = ifempty(checks.join(""), i)
  echo(toecho)
  inc(i)
```

I'm expecting it to join the array, but all I get is the error

> /home/runner/FavoriteJointLists/main.nim(18, 30) **Error:** attempting to call undeclared routine: 'join'
> **exit status 1**

Comment: These are sequences not array. Please change the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`join`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#join%2CopenArray%5Bstring%5D%2Cstring) is defined in `std/strutils`, not `std/strformat`.